# Visual Studio Datepicker And Timepicker WP7

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, user-controls

Most of you have already probably encountered this but in my Datepicker Control and in my Timepicker Control the symbols are just marked as X (no symbol).

Im only used to set the symbols normally on the xaml pages on the applicationbar. Though the Datepicker and Timepicker symbols are shown once you click on them. My question is: How can i code the controls and set the appropriate symbols since i have no experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include Toolkit.Content folder with images to your project and specify build action for icons as Content

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-datepicker-and-timepicker-in-depth--api-and-customization

[image]